# UIImageView change picture with fade effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I got 2 `ImageViews` which fade in and out with a timer but I think that needs too much memory so I want a fade animation with one `ImageView`. Is this possible ?

Comment: Why do you think it uses too much memory? Have you run Instruments to see the memory usage over time? What patterns are you seeing?

Comment: you should buy a used iPhone 3GS and test it there. you will find that it works smoothly on that old phone. so, there is no need to optimise anything.

Comment: Yes I tested it in Instruments the 2 Views+ Gif animation use 50 MB

Comment: Your post doesn't make much sense. 2 image views will not cause an excessive amount of memory use unless the images that you are loading into those image views are thousands of pixels in each dimension and the system has to scale them down to display them on-screen. If that's the case you should shrink them down to the largest screen size you'll use in an image editor and save the shrunk images to your project. If that's not the case you're going to need to post a lot more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using `UIView`'s [+ transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) method.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:yourImageView duration:7.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
       yourImageView.image = newImage;
    } completion:nil];
```